# split an argument and add include the items in url

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to solve a problem at work, where it's required to access project folders on a shared drive.

However the naming convention is a bit tricky. The URLs on the server start with the static `FS\XXX\00` followed by the project number (6 digits long) which is split into pieces of two and between slashes. For example the project folder for project `123456` would look like `FS\XXX\00\12\34\56`.

What I'm trying to sort out is how to create a `.bat` file, put it in the environment path and call it with the `Run` command, so for example I would call the file `ex.bat` by entering the following sequence in the `Run` console:

```
ex 123456
```

Then the program should split the number, build up and open the following URL:

```
FS\XXX\00\12\34\56
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see anything having to do with powershell in this question. Also, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because powershell was tagged, here's a powershell implementation. Save this as a script in the environment path somewhere:

```
[CmdLetBinding()]
param
(
    [string] $ProjectNumber = '123457'
)

$root = 'FS\XXX\00\'

# Create a string with backslashes every 2 chars
$out = (&{for ($i = 0;$i -lt $ProjectNumber.length;$i += 2)
{
$ProjectNumber.substring($i,2)
}}) -join '\'

# Create final path
$path = Join-Path -Path $root -ChildPath "$out\"

# Run explorer with the path
explorer $path
```

and call from run/cmd like this:

```
powershell "& "Script.ps1 -ProjectNumber 123456""
```

Answer (score 2):

`%1` is the first parameter. Save it to a variable (`%p%`) do be able to do substring substitution (see `set /?`) and build and output the desired string:

```
@echo off
set p=%1
echo FS\XXX\00\%p:~0,2%\%p:~2,2%\%p:~4,2%
pause
```

Comment: Thanks this worked - I've just replaced the echo with start so I can get the actual folder opened. Cheers!